# SQL Server SSIS: work as a team on the same data flow?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS and I was wondering if it is possible at all to access someone else's work? For instance, if someone created a data flow in SSIS using their user on the server, and I log in as my user, can I access and edit their work?

I know that in other ETL tools like Informatica you need to check in/out the object/data flow you are working on. Is there something similar in place in SSIS?

Comment: SSIS has VSTS (Azure DevOps or whatever it was just renamed to last week) and GitHub integration natively. You can certainly import/export projects from your teammates (or SSISDB, or ispac file...) as well, but that's not nearly the same as a repository.

Comment: Ok, but what if you're working in SSIS on the same server, but logged in as different users? Is there no way to open someone else's work?

Comment: Yes, as I said you can open the packages directly, or import the projects from SSISDB or using an ispac file. It depends on the deployment method. Assuming you have security rights to open them, of course. This is *not* the same as checking in and checking out a file, which was your question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just export and open: http://www.mssqlgirl.com/editing-published-ssis-package-in-sql-server-2012.html

Comment: And @LukaszSzozda has presented two ways. One importing from SSISDB (as I mentioned twice) and one by converting the ispac to a zip file and getting the packages directly. This assumes your deployment is in the SSISDB. Which we don't know. Hopefully this information is helping...

Comment: Check in / check out is usually done with TFS